# Avoiding unnamed lambda parameter

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, java-12

I have an application that needs to manage a priority queue of some items, where the priorities themselves can actually be fractional quantities (like 2.4 or 0.3). Smaller is better, as with usual integer priorities. The following one-liner generates a `DoubleStream` with `DEFAULT_CAPACITY` - many `double`s pseudo-uniformly distributed between `0` and `SCALE`:

```
DoubleStream priorities = IntStream.range(0, DEFAULT_CAPACITY).map(_ -> r.nextDouble() * SCALE);
```

My question is: how can I avoid the unnamed parameter `_` in the lambda that is given as an argument to `map`? Unfortunately, `Random::nextDouble()` is not `static`, so a method reference is not possible.

This question generalizes, of course: lacking a `static` method and given a known number of iterations, how can we avoid an unnecessary unnamed lambda parameter? Effectively, the generation of an intermediate `Stream` (the result of calling `IntStream::range()`), should really not be necessary.

// Edit: After looking at my IDE a bit closer, I am noting that the syntax above is actually NOT compilable since Java 9! The compiler says: *As of Java 9, '_' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier*. So this question is even more important to me now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a `Random r` object already:

```
DoubleStream priorities = r.doubles(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, 0.0, SCALE);
```

or

```
DoubleStream priorities = DoubleStream
    .generate(() -> r.nextDouble() * SCALE)
    .limit(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
```